# Can I add an NFT image to MetaMask on the Ganache test network?

Tags: web3js, metamask, erc-721, ganache

Here is my code:

```js
const addImageToMetaMask = async (_tokenAddress, _tokenName, _tokenSymbol, _urlImage, _tokenId) => {
  try {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
      const provider = window.ethereum;
      await provider.request({
        method: 'wallet_watchAsset',
        params: {
          type: 'ERC721',
          options: {
            address: _tokenAddress,
            symbol: _tokenSymbol,
            name: _tokenName,
            image: {
              src: _urlImage,
              width: '200px', 
              height: '200px' 
            },
            tokenId: _tokenId,
          },
        },
      });
      console.log('Success');
    } else {
      console.log('not metamask');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error:', error);
  }
};
```